# How can i listen div in realtime and add or remove class on mouse wheel with jquery?

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I want to add/remove a class on a specific div on mousewheel but somehow it doesnt work.

What i tried was to check if div has that class but my if statement never worked as expected.

I was expecting to scrolldown with mousewheel WHEN the remove-mask class added not WHEN mask is on screen.

Edit: Even minimal code is giving me "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." error, so i made a pen about it. https://codepen.io/kayahan/pen/YzzPwbR

```
<section class="video-section section">
    <div class="mask"></div>            
</section>

<section class="section">
    a
</section>

<section class="section">
    b
</section>



$(window).on('wheel', function (e) {

    var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;


    if (delta > 0 && $('.video-section').offset().top === 0) {
        $('.mask').addClass('remove-mask');
        $('.video-section').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', stopScrolling);
    }

    if (delta > 0 && $('.mask').hasClass('remove-mask')) {
        console.log('here is not working');
    }

    if (delta < 0 && $('.video-section').offset().top === 0) {
        $('.mask').removeClass('remove-mask');
        return false;
    }

});

function stopScrolling(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you convert to a snippet (edit question, click the snippet button in the toolbar) to provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem?  have a read of [mcve].

Comment: @freedomn-m I tried that but it said "your post contains too much code", sorry.

Comment: *minimal* amount of code to reproduce... not *all* your code ever.

Comment: @freedomn-m i made a pen about the issue now: https://codepen.io/kayahan/pen/YzzPwbR

Comment: Not really sure exactly how that's supposed to work.  But try:  your code uses `$(window).on("wheel"` and then uses `$('.video-section').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',` - change to `$(".video-section").on("wheel", ...` and it .. well, does something different.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need a solution, i've found it finally.

To listen wheel event, you can use the code about but also use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) feature of javascript. This fixed everything:

```
var scrollCount = 0;

$(window).on('wheel', function (e) {
    .
    .
    .
    .

    if (scrollCount <= 1 && removeMask.getBoundingClientRect().y <= 0) {
        $('#pagepiling').pagepiling();
    }

});
```